# How to get wifi band info. in Android?

Tags: android, wifi

I need to write a wifi scanner running on Android. It works fine except that I could not find a way to get `AccessPoint` band (`a/b/g/n`) out of that ScanResult provided by Android wifi manager.

Is there any way to get this info? Or do I need to go to lower level? (maybe impossible).

Any help would be highly appreciated.